# How can I find boats to travel on?

Tags: ferries, sea-travel

I'm going to be doing some traveling around the north coast of South America and the Caribbean. I'm not in a hurry, and I'd love to travel by boat, but I'm having a hard time finding information about ferries and boats routes in the area. Is there a good way to search for boat routes (or private boats that will take me where I want to go)?

Here are some examples of what I might like to do:

A boat between the Dominican Republic and Martinique. A boat between Martinique and French Guiana. A boat between French Guiana and Jericoacoara, Brazil. Etc.

I'm not all that particular about what type of boat it is, timely schedules, or price (within reason), I just think taking a boat might be more interesting than flying.

Comment: Except for cruise ships, most boat travel is extremely boring. I hope you are ready for that.

Comment: It is a very open question, and as far, there is no good source. You may google about cargo ship travel (e.g. https://www.cargoshipvoyages.com/, but there are many sites). You may google various sailing clubs on the zone (because of requirements, to have high sea permits, one must travel many miles, and so often clubs offer such travels (to share costs).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I once spent one day on board a cruise ship, and it bored me to death.

Comment: There don't seem to be regularly scheduled ferries among the Caribbean islands. Searching for [charter boats](https://www.google.com/search?q=martinique+charter+boat) turns up several results, however.

Comment: Have you tried guidebooks for the relevant areas?

Answer (score 3):

OK, so my friend - Kylie Phaup-Stephens, has a blog on [bugbitten](http://www.bugbitten.com/blogs/kyles/my_blogs.html).  Over the period of 20 months from ANZAC Day(25th of April) 2009 to the end of 2010, she cycled from London, UK to Christchurch, NZ.

Naturally, she had to use water methods at some point.

She struggled for a while to find a boat to Aus - and a visa (a legacy law means that even Kiwis need a visa for Australia if arriving by sea!).  However, [here is her blog entry](http://www.bugbitten.com/blogs/Worldwide/kyles/Across_the_waterIndo_to_AUSTRALIA.html) on that part of the trip.  She used [FindACrew](http://www.findacrew.net/) and other such sites, as well as asking around ports for yachts travelling from Indonesia across to Thursday Island.

Then she continued around Aus for a bit, before catching a cargo ship to NZ.  [Here's her blog entry](http://www.bugbitten.com/blogs/Australia/Oceania/kyles/Cargo_Shipping_it_HOME.html) on that part of the trip.

tl;dr - use websites like Findacrew, or ask around at the port.

Comment: She could have used a water bike :) https://itbikeswaterbikes.com/ for example